# Airflow 1.10.3 - Blank "Recent Tasks" and "DAG Runs"

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

[image: ![enter image description here]

I installed Airflow 1.10.3 on Ubuntu 18.10 and am able to add my DAGs and run them but "Recent Tasks" and "DAG Runs" in the Web UI are blank. All I see are a black dotted circle which keeps loading but nothing ever materializes.

I recently upgraded my Airflow db to MySQL to see if that would fix it but everything is still the same.

Is this a configuration issue in `airflow.cfg` or something else?

Comment: Did you run `airflow scheduler`? Airflow webserver doesn't work alone.

Comment: Yes, I'm running both `airflow webserver` and `airflow scheduler`. I've tried restarting the system and then running both again to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the DAG name can break the HTML document variable `querySelector` for "Recent Tasks" and "Dag Runs". Using the DAG name `podcast_automator_v0.1` will cause these two sections to show spinning loaders until there is at least 1 acceptable DAG name.

[image]

Taking the same dag and renaming it from `podcast_automator_v0.1` to `11` caused "Recent Tasks" and "Dag Runs" to appear:

[image]

Comment: So why did previous name "podcast_automator_v0.1" not work? I am have the same issue but I don't want to change the DAG name?

Comment: The "." in "podcast_automator_v0.1"dag name is causing the issue. If you make sure that every DAG does not contain a "." you should be fine.