# Airflow - Blank, Not showing “Recent Tasks” and “DAG Runs”

Tags: airflow

I installed Airflow on Amazon ec2, But "Recent Tasks" and "DAG Runs" in the Web UI are blank. All I see are a black dotted circle which keeps loading.

[image: DAGs list]

How can I fix it?

I've checked a similar question, but I don't think that's not my case.
[Airflow 1.10.3 - Blank "Recent Tasks" and "DAG Runs"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875185/airflow-1-10-3-blank-recent-tasks-and-dag-runs/55974860#55974860)

Comment: 1. You have to enable them?
2. Trigger one dag manually and observe it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved this problem.
It was an error caused by a python2.7 version problem. I changed the version to python3.7 and solved it.